# How do I delete a post using this with angularJS and express?

Tags: angularjs, express

I have this code in my post.serv.js and in my controller I want to execute the function delete.

```
"use strict";

app.factory('JnttPost', function ($resource) {
    var PostResource = $resource('/api/post/:_id', {
        _id: "@id"
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT',
            isArray: false
        }
    }, {
        delete: {
            method: 'DELETE',
            isArray: false
        }
    });
    return PostResource;
});
```

I already know how to get and update a post, for example in my createpost.serv.js

```
"use stric";

app.factory('JnttCreatePost', function ($http, $q, JnttPost) {

    return {

        createPost: function (newPostData) {
            var newPost = new JnttPost(newPostData);
            var dfd = $q.defer();

            newPost.$save().then(function () {
                dfd.resolve();
            }, function (response) {
                dfd.reject(response.data.reason);
            });
            return dfd.promise;
        }

    };

});
```

and in my newpost.ctrl.js

```
"use strict";

app.controller('CtrlNewPost',
    function ($scope, $location, JnttIdentity, JnttNotifier, JnttCreatePost) {

        var email = ...;

        $scope.newPost = function () {
            var newPostData = {...};

            JnttCreatePost.createPost(newPostData).then(function () {
                JnttNotifier.notify('success', 'The post has been created');
                $location.path('/');
            }, function (reason) {
                JnttNotifier.notify('error', reason);
            });

        };
    });
```

I can't realize how to perform the delete request, I can do with a $http
In my new controller for do deletePost() function I have this:

$scope.deletePost = function () {
    var pwd = JnttIdentity.currentUser.hashed_pwd;

```
var postidd = {
    password: pwd,
    id: $scope.post._id
};

var config = {
    method: "DELETE",
    url: '/api/post/',
    data: postidd,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    }
};

$http(config);
$location.path('/');
```

};

This actually already do this stuff but I want to do this without the $http like the create request, How I can do this? How do I can edit this code below for do the request?

```
createPost: function (newPostData) {
                var newPost = new JnttPost(newPostData);
                var dfd = $q.defer();

                newPost.$save().then(function () {
                    dfd.resolve();
                }, function (response) {
                    dfd.reject(response.data.reason);
                });
                return dfd.promise;
            }
```

In my routes.js in express I have this route:

```
app.delete('/api/post/', posts.deletePost);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either call delete on the $resource class you create (JnttPost) or call $delete on a post that's returned from the $resource class.

The $resource class already has get/save/query/remove/delete functions included so you don't need to add the delete (save is create/POST, so you need to include update with PUT).

Here's a sample of using your $resource class to call delete:

```
angular.module('test', ['ngResource'])
.factory('JnttPost', function ($resource) {
    var PostResource = $resource('/api/post/:_id', {
        _id: "@id"
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT',
            isArray: false
        }
    });
    return PostResource;
})
.run(function(JnttPost){
  JnttPost.delete({id: 123123123});
});
```

Comment: and How would I call the function delete from post.ctrl.js?

Comment: You'd inject JnttPost and call delete on it (passing the id). Or if you already have an object from a previous call to get/query, you can call $delete on that object.

Comment: What would be the code for that call?

 $scope.deletePost = function () {
  var pwd = JnttIdentity.currentUser.hashed_pwd;

  var postidd = {
   password: pwd,
   id: $scope.post._id
  };

  //Call the delete method, How to do it?
  
 };

Comment: `JnttPost.delete({id: $scope.post._id})` or `$scope.post.$delete()`

Comment: post.serv.js [code]"use strict";

app.factory('JnttPost', function ($resource) {
 var PostResource = $resource('/api/post/:_id', {
  _id: "@id"
 }, {
  update: {
   method: 'PUT',
   isArray: false
  }
 });
 return PostResource;
})[code] and in my post.ctrl.js would be [code]  $scope.deletePost = function () {
  var pwd = JnttIdentity.currentUser.hashed_pwd;

  var postidd = {
   password: pwd,
   id: $scope.post._id
  };

  JnttPost.delete({id: postidd})
  
 };[code] 

right?